# MySQL only, Multiple queries at once

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

MySQL 5.7,
Core 16,
Memory 64GB

My query runs about every hour. In that query i change the table structure of 5 tables.

The question is not why i'm doing this, i know there are better ways.

No the question is, i have a server of 16 cores and when i run the query it change each table one by one in sequence and use only 1 core.
Can i do something like multithreaded? I change these 5 tables at once with multiple cores. I want this in database only, no other programming language to make multiple calls at once.

```
ALTER TABLE table1 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(pk),
ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(order,status ),
ADD COLUMN `_country`                               VARCHAR(50) ,

ALTER TABLE table2 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(pk),
ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(order,status ),
ADD COLUMN `_country`                               VARCHAR(50) ,

ALTER TABLE table3 
ADD PRIMARY KEY(pk),
ADD UNIQUE `unique_index`(order,status ),
ADD COLUMN `_country`                               VARCHAR(50) ,
```

Comment: No way to make this queries to execute in parallel within one connection. Start this 5 queries in 5 separate client app copies. Or, for example, create 5 separate event procedures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"My query runs about every hour. In that query i change the table structure of 5 tables."  -- That is *not* the way to run a database!

You will need *some* other tool to run them in parallel; the mysql commandline tool does not have the facility.

To run the `ALTERs` in parallel, use the scripting mechanism of the OS.  In unix-like systems, this would be straightforward:

```
mysql -e "ALTER ..." &
mysql -e "ALTER ..." &
mysql -e "ALTER ..." &
...
```

Windows -- pull up N `cmd` windows and manually run them in separate windows.

On the other hand, it might work with `EVENTs`.  Define 5 EVENTs that run every hour at the top of the hour; each has one `ALTER`.  Be sure to `SET EVENT_SCHEDULER=ON`.

We really ought to discuss the need for adding a `PRIMARY KEY` again and again.